# Create a kind of Serial Operation Queue by intentionally awaiting/blocking in a ReceiveAsync handler

Tags: akka.net

Reading here:
https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-async-actors-using-pipeto/

> The actor’s mailbox pushes a new message into the actor’s OnReceive method once the previous call to OnReceive exits.

Followed by

> On a ReceiveActor, use ReceiveAsync where T is the type of message this receive handler expects. From there you can use async and await inside the actor to your hearts’ desire.
>
> However, there is a cost associated with this. While your actor awaits any given Task, **the actor will not be able to process any other messages sent to it until it finishes processing the message in its entirety.** (emphasis mine)

It seems to me that I can use this blocking quality to force an Actor to be a kind of serial operation queue. Yes, if the process crashes and the messages enqueued were not persisted, that will cause those messages to be lost. Assuming that is ok however, and in my case that is desirable. Are there any other reasons not to an Actor like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any other reasons not to an Actor like this?

Your overall question has a flaw in its premise, but the short answer is that you should *absolutely* use Actors in this manner.

The flaw in your question is that you are referencing a blog post that is talking about using async and PipeTo.  What you seem to be missing is that *all* Actors work this way, whether synchronous or asynchronous, and whether using PipeTo or not!

The whole idea of an Actor (at least in Akka.Net) is built around processing messages from a mailbox one at a time (a "Serial Operation Queue" as you called it).